# sound analyzer using naudio for 48000 samples/sec sound. Can I use a cycle-sample-size of 1024?

Tags: c#, audio, fft, naudio, analyzer

I need to create a sound analyzer to isolate certain song frequencies. For now, I'm interested in bass (60-250Hz).

I read the signal (IEEE float), for each block of 1024: do a FFT, and then extract the value corresponding to each frequency.

What I don't understand is this: I know FFT needs powers of 2 in order to work. I've seen code using blocks of 512, code using 2048, 4096 and so on.

I've settled on 1024 (which gives me roughly 47 datapoints/second). Am I correct in assuming that using, 2048, for instance will work just the same, giving me 23.5 datapoints/second, and the only difference is accuracy (and speed of computation of course)?

Also, am I required to read at 1024-boundary blocks? Like, for instance, say I simply skip the first 200 floats, will the results end up being very similar?  (my tests seem to say yes)

LATER EDIT: updated title to make it easier to understand

Comment: The general rule is Nyquist which says you must sample at least twice the max frequency when doing a FFT.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks! When it comes to sound, apparently I'm an idiot. If I have a 48KHz sound, how much should my sample size be? Because if I understand correctly from your comment, I would need to sample a whole second.

Comment: I said nothing about time.  I said frequency.  And nothing about sample size.  The length of the sample has to cover the input.  If you had a single frequency you just need a few periods of the sample.  If you were analyzing a song you would need the entire song.

Comment: Thanks! I'm clearly missing something here, since I don't understand. What I want to achieve is find out how the bass increases/decreases over time. If I can compute an FFT of 32768 floats, for every 1024 floats, that is fine. I want to know how can I achieve "get the bass frequency value" - I would like 30+ datapoints/second, so i can understand when it goes up/down. Does that make sense?

Comment: 30 data points a second is not enough.  According to Nyquist you will only be able to process frequencies below 15Hz.

Comment: This is insane. I simply can't wrap my head around this. How does other software do it? And more to the point, why does my approach *seem* to work? Basically, I've tested it on roughly 30 songs, and it's pretty accurate. It's not perfect, but it's working pretty well (yes, I do need to do more testing)

Comment: What is you max frequency you are looking for?  At 30 point a second how can you recognize a frequency of 100Hz?  You just have points.  If you use wrong parameters your 30 points a second could be processing like 3000 points a second.

Comment: Hypothetically, max frequency I'm looking at would be 6KHz. And what I'm doing right now, for every 1024 samples, I do an FFT and get frequencies. From those frequencies, I compute what I need (a BASS value), and move on to the next block of 1024 samples. Thus, according to my calculations, for 48KHz signal, I would get 48000 samples/sec, thus 47 datapoints per second (probably my terminology is a bit off, but by datapoint, I mean - a BASS value).

Comment: All Nyquist says is if you want 6KHz you need a minimum of 12,000 samples/sec.  Running a 48KHz/sec give better quality.Usually with a DSP algorithm you refer to TAPs of the filter.  I'm not a expert in designing filters.  So I think you have 47 TAPS with each TAP being 1024 Hz.

Comment: I'm more in the dark than when I started :) I mean, how can we hear music at very good quality, that is, at a bitrate of 44100 even for a lot of mp3, if I need 12000 samples/sec? Even to capture voice (besides BASS), we should be able to have lots of "voice" frequency values in a second, where I could see the "voice" increasing / decreasing. I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: The human ear can only hear up to 20KHz and voice up to 2KHz.  See : https://nhc.com.au/blog/human-hearing-range#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20normal%20human,about%2020%20to%2020%2C000Hz.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks. I've just been reading a bit more about the issue, and I seem to get that the FFT doesn't care about the sample size.

Comment: Right.  You can have a 1 second sample or a one minute sample.   But it does care about samples per second.  If you use the wrong samples per second you get the wrong frequencies for the output.

Comment: Got it. In hindsight, my question was completely stupidly formulated. I am using the right samples per second. And then I decided to compute frequencies for every 1024 consecutive values. As I understand, this can be any number, and I can pad zeros until the next power-of-two. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: Depends on Algorithm and Coefficients.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the algorithm, although it looks pretty solid

Comment: I do not know about the padding and power of two.

Comment: As i understand, FFT needs a power of two of data samples. And if you have less than that number, just pad zeros.

Comment: It depends on the filter type the size and padding.  FFT is just a general term and doesn't determine the size.

Comment: Here's the FFT algorithm that I use: https://github.com/swharden/FftSharp/blob/master/src/FftSharp/Transform.cs

Comment: Power of 2 reduces the number of calculations needed to get answer. It does not need to be a power of 2.  See Wiki article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

Comment: Got it! Apparently, the algorithm that I'm using needs this.

Answer (score 3):

1024/48kHz is barely longer than one period of a 60 Hz signal.  Too short to determine if the signal is even fully periodic (repeats).  Humans typically require somewhere around 6 periods of repetitions to hear a sound as a having a definite pitch.

60 Hz is B1.  You might need 2 Hz resolution to separate B1 from C1 with a clear gap in between the two nearest FFT frequency bins. To do that, just using FFT magnitude results, would require an FFT of 48kHz/2Hz or a half second, or longer.  The nearest power of 2, for 48ksps samples, is 32768.

For music pitch frequencies, there are much better pitch detector/estimators than using a bare FFT or FFT frequency peak magnitude, as they solve the missing or weak fundamental issue common in recorded instrumental or vocal music.  Those pitch estimators can work with shorter time interval windows than a half second, but require more computation than a bare FFT magnitude peak picking.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't fully understand the answer. Long story short, I need to know, for instance, when the BASS is increasing and decreasing in magnitude. I need to do this a lot of times per second, in order to detect this, otherwise, what I'm doing is useless. 
Long story short, my code *seems* to be working - I've tested it on 30 songs, and the results are accurate enough. 

Doing an FFT on 32768 is useless for me, since I would have too few datapoints. UNLESS - I could take 32768 points with a step of 1024. So basically, use a step of 1024, and then do an FFT on ...

Comment: ... the following 32768 points. That would definitely work for me, if that would be a viable option.